# Laravel passport always showing 'unauthenticate' message

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am newbie in laravel. I installed laravel 5.7 with passport . I successfully done the login and got the  user access token . Actual problem is I wrote a   route which is used to fetech user deatlis . Then I access the url with the token but it's showing unauthenticated message.

I used the laravel default server in my local system and vue axios client for request to server .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's like finding a needle in a haystack without seeing the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is adding this to `.htaccess` of root folder. it helped for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Without this configuration, the Authorization header will be ignored in your app running